# checkout_cart_configure sidebar is gone

Tags: magento-1.7, layout

First of all I am not really sure of how is the best way of checking what went wrong when what is on your xml isn't showing on the actual website.

Now for my problem, when I navigate to the checkout_cart_configure page everything shows up except for the sidebar. The xml is this one:

```
<checkout_cart_configure translate="label">
    <label>Configure Cart Item</label>
    <update handle="catalog_product_view"/>
</checkout_cart_configure>
```

Which as far as i know copies what I have inside catalog_product_view, right?

This is what I have there:

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Any)</label>
    <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>varien/configurable.js</script></action>

        <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name><params/><!--<if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css</stylesheet></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar-setup.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>lightbox/jquery.lightbox-0.5.min.js</name></action>
        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/slider.css</stylesheet></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>easing/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>slideshow/jquery.slider.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>slideshow/efects.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>hideContentProduct/hideContentProduct.js</script></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="catalog.leftnav2" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml">
            <block type="featuredcategory/featuredcategory" name="featuredcategory" template="featuredcategory/featuredcategory.phtml" />
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="left.sideboxes_producto" template="catalog/navigation/sideboxes_producto.phtml"/>
        </block> 
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">

            <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" translate="label">
                <label>Alert Urls</label>
            </block>

            <action method="setTierPriceTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml</template></action>

            <block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml" >
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>description</alias><title>Product Description</title><block>catalog/product_view_description</block><template>catalog/product/view/description.phtml</template></action>

                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>fiche</alias><title>Fiche technique</title><block>catalog/product_view_fiche</block><template>catalog/product/view/fiche.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>plusphotos</alias><title>Plus de photos</title><block>catalog/product_view_plusphotos</block><template>catalog/product/view/plusphotos.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>documents</alias><title>Documents</title><block>catalog/product_view_documents</block><template>catalog/product/view/documents.phtml</template></action>                
            </block>
            <block type="catalog/product_view_additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data" />
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="catalog/product/view/addto.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart_surface" as="addtocart_surface" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart_surface.phtml"/>

            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.extrahint" as="extrahint" translate="label">
                <label>Product View Extra Hint</label>
            </block>

            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml" translate="label">
                <label>Info  Options Wrapper</label>
                <block type="core/template" name="options_js" template="catalog/product/view/options/js.phtml"/>
                <block type="catalog/product_view_options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="catalog/product/view/options.phtml">
                    <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>text</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_text</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>file</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_file</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>select</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_select</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>date</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_date</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/date.phtml</template></action>
                </block>
                <block type="core/html_calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="page/js/calendar.phtml"/>
            </block>
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml" translate="label">
                <label>Bottom Block Options Wrapper</label>
                <action method="insert"><block>product.tierprices</block></action>
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.clone_prices" as="prices" template="catalog/product/view/price_clone.phtml"/>
                <action method="append"><block>product.info.addtocart</block></action>
                <action method="append"><block>product.info.addto</block></action>
            </block>

            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom2" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom2" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml" translate="label">
                <label>Bottom Block Options Wrapper</label>
                <action method="insert"><block>product.tierprices</block></action>
                <action method="append"><block>product.info.addtocart</block></action>
            </block>

            <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container1" as="container1">
                <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container1</value></action>
                <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
                <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
                <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom2</block></action>
            </block>
            <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container2" as="container2">
                <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container2</value></action>
                <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
                <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
                <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
            </block>

            <block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
                <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>70</columns></action>
                <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>70</limit></action> 
            </block>

            <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml">
                <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>70</columns></action>
                <action method="setItemLimit"><type>related</type><limit>70</limit></action> 
            </block>

            <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container1</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>0</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>
            <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container2</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>0</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>


        </block>
    </reference>
```

What went wrong? the html of the page shows an empty

```
 <div class="col-left sidebar"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the following block of code inside `<checkout_cart_configure translate="label">.....</checkout_cart_configure>`

```
<reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="catalog.leftnav2" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml">
            <block type="featuredcategory/featuredcategory" name="featuredcategory" template="featuredcategory/featuredcategory.phtml" />
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="left.sideboxes_producto" template="catalog/navigation/sideboxes_producto.phtml"/>
        </block> 
    </reference>
```

The Code will look like this:

```
    <checkout_cart_configure translate="label">
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="catalog.leftnav2" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml">
                <block type="featuredcategory/featuredcategory" name="featuredcategory" template="featuredcategory/featuredcategory.phtml" />
                <block type="catalog/navigation" name="left.sideboxes_producto" template="catalog/navigation/sideboxes_producto.phtml"/>
            </block> 
        </reference>
        <label>Configure Cart Item</label>
        <update handle="catalog_product_view"/>
    </checkout_cart_configure>
```

It'll resolve your problem

Comment: Yeah I figured this too, but why do I need this if I already have <update handle="catalog_product_view"/> ???

Comment: In fact this isn't working either